# How to display video as second link in thumbnail images

Tags: product-view, thumbnail, video

In product details page I have video related to the product along with the thumbnail images. The video always comes at the last. I want to display the video as second link in the thumbnail images. What changes should I do to do that?

I get the video through attribute at backend. This is my code to display it in details page:

```
<?php if($_product->getVideoEmbeded()): ?>
        <div id="video_frame" style="display: none;width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: absolute;top: 0;left: 0;"><?php echo $_product->getVideoEmbeded(); ?></div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

And here is the code to change the base image with the video:

```
<?php if($_product->getVideoEmbeded()): ?>
            <li class="item"><a href="javascript:void(0)" onClick="changemainimage('<?php echo $prurl  ?>','vdionly')" class="video_link " id="video_link"></a> </li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: How do you upload the product video ?

Comment: Kindly see the edited question.

Comment: can you view your video in the product details page?

Comment: yes I can view. I want to display my video as First or second one in thumbnail images.

Answer (score 1):

1. Just Cut the code and pasted it before the code which displayed the image.
2. Now the video is displayed in first position.