# How to display video as thumbnail image in magento

Tags: magento-1.9, thumbnail, video

How to display YouTube video as thumbnail image in Magento?

Comment: What kind of video? is it Youtube video?

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/98154/45103

Comment: yes @prasanta Hatui

Comment: That code is in which file @GopalPatel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$videourl` is youtube video url and in phtml file you can put this.

Try below code:

```
<?php 
            $posOfV = strpos($videourl,'?v=');
            if($posOfV === false) 
            {
                $explodeArr = explode("youtu.be/",$videourl);
                $embedId = $explodeArr[1];      
            }
            else 
            {
                $explodeArr = explode("?v=",$videourl);
                $pos = strpos($explodeArr,'&');
                if($pos === false)
                 {
                    $embedId = $explodeArr[1];
                 }
                else 
                {
                    $explodedAgain = explode("&",$explodeArr[1]);
                    $embedId = $explodedAgain[0];
                }

             }
        ?>
    <div>
     <iframe width="300" height="160" src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/<?php echo $embedId ?>" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
    </div>
```

Comment: where this code i want to put @prasanta Hatui

Comment: **$videourl** is youtube video url and in phtml file you can put this.

Comment: default/template/catalog/product/view/media.phtml    is it the file in which i want to put this code @prasanta Hatui

Comment: ok it's Working :) Thank you @prasanta Hatui